# Video - Could not find tag for codec wavpack in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container Could not write file MKV to MP4 with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mkv, video-conversion

Trying to convert an hour long `MKV` file into an `MP4` using *FFmpeg*, but during the conversion process it keeps giving me this error:

```
Could not find tag for codec wavpack in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

I have tried to use other converters, but they all have file size limits, It takes to long to convert with *Handbrake* and *VLC*. I tried to search for some kind of answer on google, but there has been no forum posts anywhere for a solution to this kind of issue.

Comment: I would generally expect this error to show up immediately instead of during the process. Show your command and the complete log.

Answer (score 0):

The error is your answer. Wavpack is not supported in mp4. So you muse use a container where it is supported (mkv) or convert it. You cna probablly convert just the ausio however and keep the video.

e.g.
`ffmpeg -i my.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec aac my.mp4`